# Error when saving Marketing List

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm using Dynamic CRM 2015. I want to create a Marketing List. After I click the Save button, this error appears:

[image: unexpected error message]

It worked before. But suddenly, it won't let me save the Marketing List data:

[UPDATED]
Log file:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: TrackingId: 1D105281, Depth: 1, Message: SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute: Could not create the plug-in interface from the plug-in assembly: PowerObjects.Xrm.PowerPack.PowerMailChimp.CreateGroupingandMergeTags.CreateGroupingAndMergeTagsDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: TrackingId: 1D105281, Depth: 1, Message: SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute: Could not create the plug-in interface from the plug-in assembly: PowerObjects.Xrm.PowerPack.PowerMailChimp.CreateGroupingandMergeTags.CreateGroupingAndMergeTags</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-01-11T05:56:15.147409Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[PowerObjects.Xrm.PowerPack.PowerMailChimp.CreateGroupingAndMergeTags: PowerObjects.Xrm.PowerPack.PowerMailChimp.CreateGroupingandMergeTags.CreateGroupingAndMergeTags]
[bf7fc8e7-bced-e011-9afd-000c29eb3827: PowerObjects.Xrm.PowerPack.PowerMailChimp.CreateGroupingandMergeTags.CreateGroupingAndMergeTags: Create of list]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: Could you please download the log file and update your question with it?

Comment: @FedericoJousset i added log file content to the question

Comment: Well, you're having an issue with a PowerMailChimp plugin. If you deactivate that plugin you will be able to create the list, but something could stop working. I would check that the PowerMailChimp solution installed matchs the CRM version (that error could be related to a SDK libraries mismatch) and if everything seems right I would contact for support.